# Is there any equivalent function that returns the character at position `X` in PHP?

Tags: php, string

Is there any equivalent function that returns the character at position `X` in PHP?

I went through the documentation but couldn't find any. I am looking for something like:

```
$charAtPosition20 = strCharAt(20, $myString);
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For single-byte strings you can use: `$myString[20]` (note that indices start from 0).

For multi-byte strings see the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128599/is-there-any-equivalent-function-that-returns-the-character-at-position-x-in-p#64367233)

Comment: For future readers: this works for ASCII, but if you plan on dealing with multibyte (Unicode) strings, this doesn't work. See my answer for dealing with Unicode strings.

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways you can achieve this:

1. Use square brackets and an index to directly access the character at the specified location, like: `$string[$index]` or `$string[1]`;
2. Use the `substr` function: `string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )`
   See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php for further informations.

Comment: The first way is generally better if you need a single char

Answer (score 4):

To point out a small caveat I noticed on the [Strings page of the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> **Warning** Internally, PHP strings are byte arrays. As a result, accessing or modifying a string using array brackets is not multi-byte safe, and should only be done with strings that are in a single-byte encoding such as ISO-8859-1.

The [str_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) function can break a string into an array of each of its characters (or specific-length substrings), but also does not handle multi-byte strings. However, the user comments on there offer some potential solutions.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer works well for single-byte (ASCII) strings, but **it breaks for multibyte (Unicode) strings**. For these, you need to use `mb_` functions – just make sure you have the [mbstring](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php) extension installed and enabled.

To get character at position of a multibyte string:

```
$char = mb_substr($string, $position, 1);
```

[`mb_substr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) is just like `substr` but for multibyte strings, so the `1` at the end returns only 1 character, but if you want more characters, you can change this accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind found it :)

```
echo $str[1];
```

// so obvious

Comment: The {} syntax is deprecated as of PHP 6.  Square brackets are recommended.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $myString{20};
```

or:

```
substr($mystring, 20, 1)
```

Comment: As already said in others answer's comments here, better to use [] and not {}

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the string for each char. like this.

```
$string = 'Here is the text';
echo $string[0]; // output H
echo $string[1]; // output e
echo $string[2]; // output r
```

...

Comment: this is no longer supported.

Answer (score -3):

simple and easy way!

```
$string = 'Here is the text';
echo $string{2};
```

It returns character "e" which is at the position 2.

Comment: this is no longer supported.